# Где незакрытыя скобка? Где баг? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
$(function() {

  $('.slider__inner, .news__slider-inner').slick({
    nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-btn slick-next"></button>',
    prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-btn slick-prev"></button>',
    infinite: false
  });

  $('select').styler();

  $('.header__btn-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.menu ul').slideToggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: Где баг? С чего вы взяли, что в приведенном коде есть баг?

Comment: не работает слайдер и менюшка, в инспекторе кода пишет что незакрыта скобка.

Comment: В приведенном коде нету ошибки.